# How do I embed a part of a webpage with a certain name attribute within my webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, web, embed

There's a webpage. Let's call it Example.html. I can not control/change this webpage but I want to embed a particular portion of it in my webpage.

The Example.html webpage has an HTML code that looks something like this:

```
<!--[stuff I don't want]-->
<form action="/example/index.pl" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="windyNights">

<!--[stuff I want!]-->

<\form>

<!--[stuff I don't want]-->
```

So how do I include the stuff I want in my webpage without including that stuff I don't need? is there a way to use the name attribute to isolate it somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
$('#target-div').load('http://www.example.com/Example.html form[name="windyNights"]');
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Just a blank page :O
I am a beginner so I could be missing something obvious.

Comment: <html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

<div id="m"></div>

<script language="javascript">
$('#m').load('Example.html form[name="windyNights"]');
</script> 

</body>

</html>

Comment: @LucyJones It uses jQuery. Add this line before the first `<script>`: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: ok the load function works now as long as I don't include the part (form[name="windyNights"]) once it's there the page goes blank again. I still can't get it to select the specific form based on its name. Help?

Comment: nvm. it runs on firefox, just not chrome for some reason. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use iframe and a specific id of that particular div that you want to show and set the height and width of the iframe according to your target div.
see the example:

```css
#project_summary {
 width: 600px;
 height: 220px;
 padding: 15px 10px;
    background:black;
}
```

```html
<iframe id="project_summary" src="https://towkir.github.io/projectindex/projects.html#rsp" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

visit the link in the iframe separately to understand what is going on.

Comment: The specific div that I want (which is actually a <form>) does not have an id. only a name attribute. Is there a way to use the name instead of the id to find the required section?

Comment: @LucyJones simply replace the id with the name, after the # sign.
both should work. example:
in the following link, #Notes is an id.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/anchors#Notes
and in here, #h-12 is a name.
https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12
Hope this helps